# Swift/ObjC: IBOutlets shown as `not bound` from Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Ever since `Xcode 6`, when you bind objects from a `Storyboard`/`xib` file to a variable in your class, they often show `not bound` in the class.
So, finding the corresponding `Storyboard`/`xib` file then is more slow, as you have to manually go, and open the corresponding file (assuming you know exactly where that view controller lives among all `Storyboard`/`xib` file in your code).

There's seems to be no workaround out there.

Has anyone found the same issue? And along with this, has anyone found a workaround?

[image: Unbound IBOutlets]

Comment: I'm assuming you've already tried cleaning the project and deleted the contents in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` to force Xcode to reindex?

Comment: I have this same issue. There seems to be no quick workaround.

Comment: I have seen where the dots are empty, but everything works as expected. Does your app still work, or not?

Comment: One way that *may* works is to dump all the information from the storyboard to a plist file: `ibtool --all Main.storyboard > StoryboardInfo.plist`. It has a section that define all the connections. Sadly, I don't have the time to fully explore it

Comment: @CodeDifferent. Thanks, this helped to at least find more directly the Storyboard/xib file where the variable is bounded. And yes, I tried removing the derived data to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

There are many disappointing bugs in Xcode, and this one of them. After you navigate to Storyboard containing these outlets, Xcode eventually find these bindings and will show them appropriately.

Comment: Yep, this works as long as you know which Storyboard/xib file bounds those variables, otherwise you'll have to open all Storyboards you have.

Comment: Apple has Radar for filling bug reports, but as far as I can tell they don't give a shit about it :) There are many waaay more hardcore bugs in Xcode, especially with Swift.